# system command not running exe file using variable as param

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I am writing code to download an app from server in visual studio 2005(VC++). After downloading it when I start running it line 3 does not run the exe file while if I write it as

```
system("c:/pg/ap/app.exe")
```

it starts running.
Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

```
1.const char * str; 
2. HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile ( NULL, _T("file_path/app.exe"),(LPCWSTR)str,0,NULL);
3. system(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using `System()` function, try `ShellExecute()`, it ll solve your problem.

For more help refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)